# Get scripthash for known scriptPubKey in PHP

Tags: address, electrum, php

I have to query addresses in ElectrumX server. How do I generate scripthash for a known scriptPubKey in PHP?

Example address:

```
array (
  'isvalid' => true,
  'address' => '1MUz4VMYui5qY1mxUiG8BQ1Luv6tqkvaiL',
  'scriptPubKey' => '76a914e0ad60c897901128662623c500a4a6079e99cd3e88ac',
  'isscript' => false,
  'iswitness' => false,
)
```

I tried:

```
hash('sha256', hex2bin('76a914e0ad60c897901128662623c500a4a6079e99cd3e88ac'))
```

But it seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution replicating https://github.com/janoside/btc-rpc-explorer/blob/master/app/api/electrumAddressApi.js

```
$scriptPubKey = '76a914e0ad60c897901128662623c500a4a6079e99cd3e88ac';

$addrScripthash = hash('sha256', hex2bin($scriptPubKey));
$re = '/.{2}/';
preg_match_all($re, $addrScripthash, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER, 0);
$addrScripthash = implode('', array_reverse($matches[0]));

print($addrScripthash);
```